# Is there a way to execute task from a queue after a particular timeout in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue

Let us assume that I have `n` different number of tasks and a stream of tasks are coming with different given `time(t)`. Is there a way to ensure that each task gets executed after their given `time(t)`? I'm using python to create and execute these tasks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep the required execution times in a sorted list.
Wait till the time present at the beginning of the list.
Remove the first item from the list and execute the task.
Repeat.

Comment: in this approach every time a new job with time( t) comes in the queue, I'll have to rearrange the queue. And this will increase the time complexity of the problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's impossible to reach the O(1) complexity for both `insert` and `remove` operations. Anyway, look at the `bisect` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html, namely the `bisect.insort`.

Comment: @Shail. How big is your queue?? `append` followed by `sort` is O(n) when the `list` is presorted. Usually this works well enough and is easily understood.